# SQL Join Tables simple approach needed

Tags: sql, join, merge, concatenation, outer-join

im looking for a simple logic to merge two tables and expected result is given below.

is it possible to achieve it using SQL join or concatenate commands?

how can i achieve it?

here is the logic I'm working on and trying to find solution:

TABLE 1:

```
ID  Name        Title               Age
2   Paul        Technical Support   22
4   Janne       IT Specialist       27
1   Wladimir    Team Lead           31
3   Mark        Customer Support    40
```

TABLE 2:

```
ID  Name        Title               Age
2   Paul        Technical Support   22
4   Janne       IT Specialist       
1   Wladimir                        31
3   Mark        Customer Support    40
```

Expected result after merge:

```
ID  Name        Title               Age
2   Paul        Technical Support   22
4   Janne       IT Specialist       27
1   Wladimir    Team Lead           31
3   Mark        Customer Support    40
```

[image]

Comment: Join the tables and use `nvl`, `isnull` or similar function to get the non-missing value, depending on what RDBMS you're using

Comment: The results after the merge are the same as `table1`.  No merge seems necessary at all.  Your question should also have an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the following query for this

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t1.title,t1.age,t2.id,t2.name.t2.title,t2.age from table1 t1 join table2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: while merging will duplicate rows of id 4 and 1 due to blank values  in table 2?

Comment: hey, sorry
Try using distinct with your t1.id

Comment: i think,  after join, seems max value  grouping of columns might help. instead of ditinct.